# Event listener on multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

On the site I have a navbar. When I click on the `a` in navbar I want a new `div` (with content) appears and everything else "hides". I did it with`display: none`. In the corner there should be an "X" which closes the div and makes "first screen" appear again.

I did the first part, but have some problems with closing. Here is my code:

```
const about = document.getElementById('li-about');
const work = document.getElementById('li-work');
const contact = document.getElementById('li-contact');
```

^These are links in a navbar.

```
const openSlide = (id) => {
document.querySelector('main article#' + id).style.display = 'block';
document.querySelector('header').style.display = 'none';
};

about.addEventListener('click', () => openSlide('about'));
work.addEventListener('click', () => openSlide('work'));
contact.addEventListener('click', () => openSlide('contact'));
```

And here is the code. It works. But when I want to do similar thing to a closing div function, it only works with `about`, not `work and contact`.

```
const closeSlide = (id) => {
document.querySelector('main article#' + id).style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('header').style.display = 'block';
};

const close = document.querySelector('.close');
close.addEventListener('click', () => closeSlide('about'));
close.addEventListener('click', () => closeSlide('work'));
close.addEventListener('click', () => closeSlide('contact'));
```

Can you tell me why? There is no error in console, I tried to replace `closeSlide` function with a simple `console.log` and it doesn't work as well. Is it possible that JavaScript detects only one (first in HTML code) `.close` div?

Comment: How about a fiddle?

Comment: I don't think that it's complicated enough to make a fiddle, which would contain tones of html and css code. Anyway, issue is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible that JavaScript detects only one (first in HTML code) .close div?

Yes, [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first matching element it finds in the DOM. If you want to add your listeners to every `.close` on the page, either loop through the NodeList returned by [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
const closeList = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
closeList.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => closeSlide('about'));
  element.addEventListener('click', () => closeSlide('work'));
  element.addEventListener('click', () => closeSlide('contact'));
};
```

or add a listener to an element containing all of your `.close` elements that only takes action if a `.close` was clicked:

```
document.querySelector('#some-container').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (!evt.target.closest('.close')) return;
  closeSlide('about');
  closeSlide('work');
  closeSlide('contact');
});
```